# Plotting Error in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Having an issue with printing my matlab plots into a PDF. After researching for a solution for several hours I have been unable to find a solution. I keep getting the same error message. I appreciate your help.

```
x = [2 4 7 2 4 5 2 5 1 4];
fig=plot(x);
print(fig,'-dpdf')



Error using
checkArgsForHandleToPrint>LocalCheckHandles
(line 88)
MATLAB Graphics handle must be a figure.

Error in checkArgsForHandleToPrint (line 30)



Error in print>LocalCreatePrintJob (line 336)
    handles = checkArgsForHandleToPrint(0,
    varargin{:});

Error in print (line 153)
    [pj, inputargs] =
    LocalCreatePrintJob(varargin{:});
```

Comment: The first input should be a handle to a *figure* you are passing a handle to a *plot*. Try `print(gcf, '-dpdf')` to print the current figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot` returns the handle to a graphics object of type `'Line'` which is at least two levels below `'Figure'`.   But the `print` function expects a figure (as the error message says).

Set  `fig=gcf` instead of setting it to the output of `plot()`.  That stands for "get current figure".  Alternatively, you can take advantage of the convention that, at least by default, figure handles are equal to the integer numbers that you see in the figure title bars—so if you want to print figure 1, you could say `print(1, '-dpdf')`

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggest but I am stil not getting it to work.x = [2 4 7 2 4 5 2 5 1 4];
fig=gcf;
plot(x);
print(1,'-dpdf')

Comment: The first argument to `print` should be the correct figure handle. That might be 1 or it might not be (that was just an illustrative example in my answer—you might be looking at figure 2, or 3, or whatever...). Generally `gcf` should work as the first argument to `print` (either directly or via variable `fig`)